# Connection Reset When Trying to Interact With a Minecraft Server in Python

Tags: python, sockets, minecraft, packets

I have a bit of a problem with attempting to send packets to a Minecraft 1.1 SMP Server.

I have the following file (ServerConnect.py):

```
import socket
import struct

username = "JackBeePeeBot"
host = "smp.project-vanilla.com:2224"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("smp.project-vanilla.com", 2224))
packet = ""
packet += struct.pack(">B", 2)
packet += username
packet += ";"
packet += host
s.send(packet)
print(s.recv(1024))
```

However, when I try to run this I get the following:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ServerConnect.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(s.recv(1024))
 socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

For anyone unaware of the packet specifications of MineCraft, they can be found here:

http://wiki.vg/Protocol

I'm trying I send a 'handshake'.

Does anyone know what's going wrong, why and how to fix it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In other Minecraft code samples in Python, I see they are packing `>B` with 2: `pack(">B", 2)`.

Comment: Nope, still not working. Thanks though. :)

Comment: I think what you're missing is the string length (encoded as 2 bytes), just before you concatenate the username. See `pack_string` in https://github.com/sadimusi/MVHP/blob/master/mvhp.py .

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to encoding in Python. Care to explain? ;)

Comment: Just before the line of code where you add the username to the packet, you need a line of code that adds the string length to the packet: `packet += struct.pack(">h", len(username) + len(";") + len(host))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol documentation says that a "string" is a 2-byte length plus the string bytes in UCS-2 (two characters each). Also, all datatypes are signed.

You should probably try something like this:

```
import struct

data = {'user':u'JackBeePeeBot','host':u'smp.project-vanilla.com','port':2224}
stringfmt = u'%(user)s;%(host)s:%(port)d'
string = stringfmt % data
structfmt = '>bh'
# 1 byte header, 2 byte *character* (not byte) string length
# and ucs-2/utf-16 BE encoded string
packetbytes = struct.pack(structfmt, 2, len(string))+string.encode('utf-16BE')
```

`packetbytes` is what you should send.

Comment: Works like a dream, but could you explain it a bit more?
_Many_ thanks, and sorry for being so annoying/stupid, but I'm new to this stuff as I hope you understand. If you don't want to explain, just a reference to a page where I can research this would do.

Comment: I just read the protocol description page you link to and paid close attention to the "Data Types" section, especially for `string`. Not sure what there is to explain?

Comment: I was just wondering where the bit where you used len(string) came from? I'm guessing it came from `Total Size: 3 bytes + length of strings` in the protocol table, but what does that actually mean? What/where are these 3 bytes, and how did you know where to put the string length?

Comment: Every packet is 1 byte header and then a payload. The payload of a handshake is one field of type "string". The **Data Types** section says a string is "UCS-2 string, big-endian. Prefixed by a short containing the length of the string in characters." So that's what I did!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that bit! +1 :)

Comment: Hey man, I've used what I gained from this, and I hate to say it, but I need more help. I made this, which sends a login packet afterwards: http://pastebin.com/VTRbzKuf The paste is all commented up with the problem.

Comment: Just read the protocol docs more carefully. You're missing the "Protocol Version" field, and an "empty string" is two bytes, not zero bytes. `enc_user = data['user'].encode('utf-16BE'); struct.pack('>bih'+str(len(enc_user))+'shiibBB', 0x01, 22, len(data['user']), enc_user, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`. An easy sanity check is to set all strings to length 0 and see if the length of your generated packet matches the minimum length for that packet type.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8485/discussion-between-jack-beepee-and-francis-avila)

Comment: It doesn't work :( just says (in server log) 127.0.0.1:(someport) lost connection :(